# Drupal form validation repeat form error twice

Tags: drupal, drupal-forms

I created custom module for render a form into a tpl file.
Everything is working fine except form validation.
The problem is,its showing form validation error if i enter the correct input into the form

I need to press submit button two times,Then only the error is cleared.

$form = drupal_get_form('custom_form')
render $form;

Comment: have you created a hook_form_submit for this custom form ? 
You can use drupal_set_message() function to override message , see this following link :
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7 Or unset session message like unset($_SESSION ['messages']); at the begining of you hook_form_submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hook Implementation:
   I had resolved this issue by implementing the hook as given below

```
  custom_preprocess_page(&$variables)
  {
    $variables['custom_form_name'] = drupal_get_form('custom_form');
  }
```

Template File:

```
<?php print render($custom_form_name); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In you hook_form_submit you can try this :

```
function mymodule_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
         unset($_SESSION ['messages']); // Remove all existing message
         .... your code testing etc...

        // Display custom message
        // success 
        drupal_set_message(t('Success'));

        // Warning
        drupal_set_message(t('Warning'), 'warning');


        // error
        drupal_set_message(t('Error'),'error');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution,yes i used hooks such as custom_form_validate and custom_form_submit

Comment: This solution fix your issue ? :)

Answer (score 0):

While using `drupal_set_message` Pass the third parameter explicitly as `FALSE`

**For example:**

`drupal_set_message($message = NULL, $type = 'status', $repeat = FALSE)`, by default `$repeat` is set to true, hence you get more than once.
FYI
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7